# Strategies for migrating medium-sized code base from Java 1.4.2 to Java 5

Tags: java, refactoring, migration

I'm in the process of reviewing a code base (~20K LOC) and trying to determine how to migrating it from 1.4.2 to 5. Obviously, it's not an overnight project and the suggestion which I have received is to write new code against Java 5 and migrate the old code in a piece-meal fashion. Also, I'm no expert in the new features in Java 5 (i.e. I know of them, but have never written any for production use).

My questions:

1. What features of Java 5 are typically used in production code? (i.e. generics, auto-boxing, etc.) Are there features to be avoided / not considered to be best-practices?
2. What are the best refactoring strategies which I can use migrate a code base of this size? (i.e. make changes to classes one at a time only when a class is edited, etc.) Objective - reduce risk on the code base. Limitation - resources to do refactoring.

Any advice is appreciated - thanks in advance.

**UPDATE - a year too late, but better late than never? =)**

Thank you for all of the comments - lots of great points of view. In the life of a software developer, there's always going to be the projects you strive to finish but never get around to because of something more "urgent".

With respect to the use of Java 5 (at that time), it was something which was required in the client's production environment, so that was why we did not use Java 6.

I found that the stronger typing for collections, enums and unboxing of primitives were the features I tend to apply the most, both to old and new code. The refactoring was fairly straight-forward, but code comprehension improved significantly and standards became easier to enforce. The ones I had the most trouble with was the generics; I think it's a concept which I still haven't had a chance to fully grasp and appreciate yet, so it was difficult for me to find previous cases where the application of generics was appropriate.

Thanks again to everyone who contributed to this thread and apologies for the late follow up.

Comment: I hope you use IntelliJ or the like as this has autofixes for most of the changes.

Comment: @Peter No unfortunately, we didn't have access to IntelliJ. Just Eclipse.

Comment: IntelliJ community edition is free.  You could just use it as your JDK 1.4 to 5.0 migration tool and nothing else. ;)  The most auto-fixes/conversions I have ever done and checked in from one run was 7K. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java 5 is almost completely backwards compatible with Java 4.  Typically, the only change you **must** make when you migrate is to rename any usages of the new `enum` keyword in the Java 4 code.

The full list of potential compatibility problems is listed here:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/compatibility.html

The only other one that I've run into in practice is related to the change in the JAXP implementation.  In our case, it simply meant removing xerces.jar from the classpath.

As far as refactoring goes, I think that migrating your collection classes to use the new strongly-typed generic versions and removing unnecessary casting is a good idea.  But as another poster pointed out, changing to generic collections tends to work best if you work in vertical slices.  Otherwise, you end up having to add casting to the code to make the generic types compatible with the non-generic types.

Another feature I like to use when I'm migrating code is the @Override annotation.  It helps to catch inheritance problems when you're refactoring code.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html

The new concurrency library is very useful if your code uses threading.  For example, you may be able to replace home-grown thread pools with a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html#concurrency

I would definitely take the approach of updating the code as you change it during normal maintenance.  Other than the compatibility issues, I don't think there is a compelling reason to use the new Java 5 features unless you're already changing the code for other reasons.

Comment: +1 for not making it seem like a massive task to migrate from 1.4 to 5 when it isn't, especially for a small project like the original poster's.

Answer (score 2):

There is one very real issue with the "viral" nature of generics; once you start introducing them at a given layer in an architecture you generally want to introduce it at the layer above & below as well. I have found that introducing generics is probably best done in full "verticals". But you do not have to do *all* the verticals at once.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really hard question to answer because it depends on what code will be affected and how critical that code is.

First and foremost, when migration is a nontrivial undertaking, do yourself a favour and upgrade to the latest version of Java, which would be Java 6 not Java 5. Java 6 has been out for a year and a half or more and is mature. There's no reason to not pick it over Java 5 (imho).

Secondly, like any software project, your goal should be to get something into production as soon as you possibly can. So you need to identify a slice of your system. The smaller the better, the more non-cdritical, the better.

The other thing to do is just try starting up your app under Java 6 and seeing what breaks. It might be worse than you expected. It might be much better.

The other thing you'll probably need to be aware of is that by the sounds of it you will have jars/libraries in your app that have since been deprecated. Some may not even be compatible with Java beyond 1.4.2. You will probably want to upgrade all of these to the latest version as well.

This will probably mean more stuff breaking but using old/deprecated APIs is just kicking the can down the street and causes you other problems.

There are exceptions to this where upgrading can have far-reaching consequences. Axis1 to Axis2 comes to mind. Those situations require more careful thought.

As for what features are used... all of them pretty much. I can't think of any that should be avoided off the top of my head.

Also, I just noticed the size of your project: ~20K LOC. That's actually quite small (eg I've written an app about that size in the last 3 months by myself).

Lastly, this also depends on how easily you will find things that break. If you have good unit test coverage then great. That's pretty rare though. If you can just run through the app and reliably find problems it's not too bad.

The problematic situations are where scenarios are hard to test and it's likely you won't uncover problems straight away. That calls for more caution.

Comment: J2SE 5.0 is in its End-Of-Service-Life period. Java SE 6 if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to migrate stuff that doesn't work in the transition from 1.4 to 5 (not sure what that would be), but I'd be wary of migrating stuff for the *sake* of it.

If you do take this route, some questions:

Do you have comprehensive test coverage ? If not, you should write unit tests for the code you're going to be migrating.

Do you have components that are widely used within your codebase ? If so, they are probably candidates to be migrated in terms of their API (e.g. using generics etc.)

In terms of what's widely used from Java 5. Generics is important and makes your life a lot easier. I don't see autoboxing *too* much, nor enums (this is all relative). Varargs almost never. Annotations are useful for frameworks, but I consume these. I don't think I've ever implemented one myself.

Answer (score 1):

20 (non-comment) kloc should be small enough to insert generics with a big bang. Obviously make sure your code compiles an runs on Java SE 5 first. The relatively easy thing about generics is that adding them makes very little change to semantics (certain overloadings can change because of implicit cases - `Iterator<char[]> iter; ... System.out.println(iter.next());` as a bad example off the top of my head).

Some cases adding generics will highlight conceptual problems with the code. Using one `Map` as two maps with disjoint key sets, for example. `TreeMap` is an example in the Java library where a single class has two distinct mode (using `Comparator<T>` or `Comparable<T>`).

Things like enhanced-for and auto-boxing are very local and can be added piecemeal. enums are rarer and might take some thinking about how you are actually going to use them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going about this the wrong way.  Your plan shouldn't be to update all current code to Java 1.5, your plan should be to ensure that all current code runs exactly the same in 1.5 as it did in 1.4.2, and that all future code written will work fine in 1.5.

I've gone through a few transitions like this of varied sized code bases.  The goal was always to make sure we had a ton of unit tests so that we could easily plug in 1.5 and run our tests through it.  We actually encountered about 10 problems, mostly related to regular expression libraries not supporting something or supporting something differently.

Write all new code in 1.5 then, and if you change an older class for whatever reason, spend a minute and implement generics, but there's no reason to refactor everything.  That sounds a bit dangerous to me if you don't have the tests in place.